# Why doesn't Mui Container horizontally center content like it's described to?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, centering

Adding description to post this. Why does the code below not horizontally center the button and box? I have to add something like `display: flex` and `align-content: center` in order to center the content. Shouldn't the Container do what it's described to?

Code taken from their docs: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-container/#fluid

```
import * as React from 'react';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';

export default function SimpleContainer() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Container maxWidth="sm">
        <Button variant='contained'>Button</Button>
        <Box sx={{ bgcolor: '#cfe8fc', height: '100vh', width: 200 }} />
      </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

[image]
[image]
https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-euler-95e99k?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `Container` with `Grid`. `Grid` has alignment props such as `justifyContent`.

```
<Grid maxWidth="sm" container justifyContent="center">
  <Box sx={{ bgcolor: "#cfe8fc", height: "100vh", width: 200 }}>
    <Button variant="contained">Button</Button>
  </Box>
</Grid>
```

It also has `maxWidth` that accept `sm` but it works a bit differently than `Container`'s so if `Grid`'s `maxWidth` doesn't work as you like, you can wrap the `Grid` with `Container`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-center-inner-items-dup6rf

---

Why it works in their example? The inner item is not centered, it's just take all the available space and the gaps around is the padding of the `Container`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it really doesn’t answer my question of why their component doesn’t work as described.

Comment: Oh, I understand the question now. Although I'm not sure about the exact meaning behind the sentence, I believe that when they mention "centers" they are referring to content that spans the full width but you probably guessed that too :)